# tcolorbox extruded and broken through pages

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

I would create, with the `tcolorbox` package (maybe with some "ifthen-like" package...), a breakable box which is extruded of a positive amount, on the left in the even pages and on the right in the odd ones, yet that such a rule is also valid when a break occurs.

I attach below a skinny file, in which a breakable `tcolorbox` appears along three different pages, though there no attempt of doing what I'm looking for is done. As you can image, the problem is mostly due to the mid and the last broken boxes...

```
\documentclass[openright]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=360pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    %extrude left by=???,
    %extrude right by=???,
    breakable,
    title={wider box}]%
\lipsum[1-12] 
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tcolorbox` already has all the options you need.

`enhanced` and `breakable` to have breakable boxes,
`toggle enlargement=evenpage` to grow right-left according to the even-odd pages.

I set `grow to right by` because I think you want to grow the box where the page margin is larger. If you actually want to grow on the left in the even pages, just set `grow to left by`.

```
\documentclass[openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=360pt}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced, breakable,
    toggle enlargement=evenpage,
    grow to right by=2cm,
    title={wider box}]
    \lipsum[1-12] 
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1-7] 
\end{document}
```

[image]